# Python: from vertical line user input to list

Tags: python

I know how to change horizontal user input to became a list.

```
numbers = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
```

but not sure how to do if the user input is vertical(enter after input integer:224, 32, 5)...

example input:

> 224 32 5

example output:

> [224, 32, 5]

Comment: you have to understand that pressing enter will make the `input` function return the line that was written by the user. There is no going back. If you want more numbers, your only option is to call `input` multiple times. however, you should use `raw_input` when getting user input.

Answer (score 3):

```
number_read = raw_input()
number_list = []
while number_read != 'q':
  number_list.append(int(number_read))
  number_read = raw_input()
```

So as soon as a user writes `q` and presses enter, you will be done collecting input

Comment: Thank you so much! Your kind answer was really helpful however I found out your code adds input gradually(output: [224], [224, 32], [224, 32, 5]) and I want to know how can I get the last line of output. Thanks! :)

Comment: In python there is no such thing as a `vertical list`. What are you trying to achieve? How are you getting your input? the `input()` function terminates if the user presses enter, so you can not even read the numbers as you think you'd read them. Also, don't use the function `input`, instead use `raw_input`. The only other potion is reading the list from a file, because as I said... if the user hits enter, you will only get 1 number, not a list. It's how `input` and `raw_input` work. please explain more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for my vague and lack explanation. I was talking about putting input for several times by pressing enter button, but not at once by spacing between two numbers. Plus, because of the version difference(2.7version works but not for the 3.2.3 version) raw_input doesn't work for me and I get undefined variable for it.                                                   224
32
[224]
5
[224, 32]
(blank)
[224, 32, 5] (ValueError occurs on .append() line)                                                                               And what I want for output is just one line ->  [224, 32, 5]

Comment: '224' '32' [224] '5' [224, 32] (blank) [224, 32, 5] (' ' marks means input)

Answer (score 1):

As @vlad-ardelean mentioned you can create a list and by means of "append" comand add its parameter as a single element to the list. However if your given input is going to be a Python list (or any other iterable such as a tuple) you can convert it to a string for display:

```
inputNumbers = input_list()
Buffer= []
Buffer += [('%03X' % ord(x)) for x in inputNumbers]
Vertical_list = []
Vertical_list= '\n'.join(map(str, Buffer))
```

Comment: What's `Input_list()`? BTW, style-wise, Python variable should be written all lower-case and with underscores between words.

Comment: Assuming `Input_List` is a function that returns a list, you can write the code like this (you don't need 3 lines there): `numbers = Input_list(); vertical_list = ', '.join(str(element) for element in numbers)` - though the `vertical_list` variable is not a comma separated "horizontal" string.... Did you want to say `'\n'.join` instead of `', '.join` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Python is a case-sensitive language and for example Variable and variable are not the same however it does not mean variables should be written all lower-case. Furthermore, multiple words can be separated using an underscore but it's not a must. Instead I could use camel-case style of writing, i.e., capitalize every first letter of the word except the initial word without any spaces. I agree with you for your last point about `\n` :)

Answer (score 0):

If finite number of input is there then use this:

```
p,q=(int(input()) for _ in range(2))
pq=[p]
```

user input:

```
5
6
```

print(pq)

```
[5,6]
```